# .pw domain name risks

Tags: domains, spam

I am considering using a set of `.pw` domain names to provide CNAME access to content stored on a CDN.  I have come across recent articles about how the `.pw` domain has become associated with spam.  Given that I will not  be using the domain to deliver mail should I care?

Put it another way, - suppose I deliver an HTML page that contains:

```
<img src='http://example.pw/images/myimg.png'/> or
<script src='http://example.pw/js/myjs.js'></script>
```

Need I be concerned that a browser may automatically block download of that resource - or a firewall may do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, browsers are not blocking it. On my system, Linux, with Firefox 27, Opera 12.16, dillo 3.0.3, seamonkey 2.24 and konqueror 4.11.5, some pages just random from Google, all worked fine.

Only konqueror had some troubles. The message was related to a malformed URL.

I wouldn't be concerned about that, specially if you are using it properly.

Although, there are some problems with spam, and so, mail clients may be blocking that domain if they follow recommendations from some web sites.

Comment: Since I made that post I came across a Symantec blog that talks about how directi - the company that now owns .pw - have worked with them to eliminate the spammy websites.  From what I can gather this was an issue in early-mid 2013.

Comment: The information I found about blocking that domain on mail applications is also not very recent, although still may be active on some private mail servers. But I don't think is going co cause you problems.